# Advice On Python Beginner's Assignment

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time understanding the idea of a function within a function.

For example, I am including the parameters of `time_from_utc` into the function `to_24_hour_clock`. It is as if I am replacing the parameters of `to_24_hour_clock` with the parameters of `time_from_utc`, and I don't really understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

```
        def to_24_hour_clock(hours):
    """ (number) -> number
```

```
hours is a number of hours since midnight. Return the
hour as seen on a 24-hour clock.

Precondition: hours >= 0

>>> to_24_hour_clock(24)
0
>>> to_24_hour_clock(48)
0
>>> to_24_hour_clock(25)
1
>>> to_24_hour_clock(4)
4
>>> to_24_hour_clock(28.5)
4.5
"""

return hours % 24
```

#### Write your get_hours function definition here:

def get_hours(seconds):
    """ (int) -> int

```
Input a time in seconds and it will return the
total number of hours that the inputted time contains.

Precondition: seconds >= 0

>>> get_hours(3600)
1.0
>>> get_hours(3500)
0.9722222222222222
>>> get_hours(17363)
4.823055555555555
>>> get_hours(177329)
49.25805555555556
>>> 
"""

return seconds / 3600
```

#### Write your get_minutes function definition here:

def get_minutes(seconds):
    """ (int) -> int

```
Input a time in seconds and it will return the
total number of minutes that the inputted time contains.

Precondition: seconds >= 0

>>> get_minutes(3600)
60.0
>>> get_minutes(240)
4.0
>>> get_minutes(90)
1.5
"""

return seconds % 60
```

#### Write your get_seconds function definition here:

```
""" (int) -> int

Input a time in seconds and it will return the
total number of seconds

>>> get_seconds(3930)
30
"""

return seconds
```

def time_to_utc(utc_offset, time):
    """ (number, float) -> float

```
Return time at UTC+0, where utc_offset is the number of hours away from
UTC+0.

>>> time_to_utc(+0, 12.0)
12.0
>>> time_to_utc(+1, 12.0)
11.0
>>> time_to_utc(-1, 12.0)
13.0
>>> time_to_utc(-11, 18.0)
5.0
>>> time_to_utc(-1, 0.0)
1.0
>>> time_to_utc(-1, 23.0)
0.0
"""
```

def time_from_utc(utc_offset, time):
    """ (number, float) -> float

`Return UTC time in time zone utc_offset.

>>> time_from_utc(+0, 12.0)
12.0
>>> time_from_utc(+1, 12.0)
13.0
>>> time_from_utc(-1, 12.0)
11.0
>>> time_from_utc(+6, 6.0)
12.0
>>> time_from_utc(-7, 6.0)
23.0
>>> time_from_utc(-1, 0.0)
23.0
>>> time_from_utc(-1, 23.0)
22.0
>>> time_from_utc(+1, 23.0)
0.0
"""

return to_24_hour_clock(utc_offset + time)`

Some tests failed:

> [TestGetSeconds] Your code raised an unexpected exception: module 'a1' has no >attribute 'get_seconds'
>
> [TestGetSeconds] Your code raised an unexpected exception: module 'a1' has no >attribute 'get_seconds'
>
> [TestGetSeconds] Your code raised an unexpected exception: module 'a1' has no >attribute 'get_seconds'
>
> [TestGetSeconds] Your code raised an unexpected exception: module 'a1' has no >attribute 'get_seconds'
>
> [TestTimeToUtc] Your code raised an unexpected exception: unsupported operand >type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
>
> [TestTimeToUtc] Your code raised an unexpected exception: unsupported operand >type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
>
> [TestTimeToUtc] Your code raised an unexpected exception: unsupported operand >type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
>
> [TestTimeToUtc] Your code raised an unexpected exception: unsupported operand >type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: Lots of those errors say `module 'a1' has no attribute 'get_seconds'` and you don't have a function called `get_seconds`. The second lot are because you don't return anything from the `time_to_utc` function

Comment: It appears that you deleted your `get_seconds` function from your assignment.  The error says it is not defined, and I don't see any `def get_seconds(seconds):` line in the code you posted.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Why do you think you have a function within a function? It's not clear where that might be from the alignment in this question

Comment: @doctorlove it was a misunderstanding. The test advised that I could look at the body of to_24_hour_clock for a hint on how to continue, not actually to incorporate it in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without all the comments so we can see the code you have

```
def to_24_hour_clock(hours):
    return hours % 24

def get_hours(seconds):
    return seconds / 3600

def get_minutes(seconds):
    return seconds % 60

### Write your get_seconds function definition here:

    return seconds


def time_to_utc(utc_offset, time):
    """
    OK, one comment - this returns nothing, so calling it give you None
    """

def time_from_utc(utc_offset, time):
    return to_24_hour_clock(utc_offset + time)
```

There are two obvious problems.

First we don't have a `get_seconds` function.

```
### Write your get_seconds function definition here:
def get_seconds(whatever)
    seconds = whatever #think about this
    return seconds
```

Next, `time_to_utc` doesn't have a return statement, so doesn't return anything.

Aside from the errors you report, in this function

```
def time_from_utc(utc_offset, time):
    return to_24_hour_clock(utc_offset + time)
```

`time_from_utc` takes two parameters called `utc_offset` and `time`, for example 1 (hour) and 12:00 (or however this is prepresented).
It calls `to_24_hour_clock` with the result of the sum `utc_offset + time`, in our case 1pm which will become 13:00 ona 24 hour clock.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback to everyone. As stated before, I had deleted the get_seconds function. Also, def get seconds(seconds): return seconds // 3600. def get_minutes(seconds): return (seconds % 3600) // 60 and finally def get_seconds(seconds): return ((seconds % 3600) % 60). The original confusion of a function inside a function was due to my misunderstanding of the instructions. The instructions simply had meant to look at the body of the function to_24_hour_clock for hints, not actually incorporate it in my calculations. I appreciate everyone's help.